# How can I share the screen using Cefsharp Winform?

Tags: c#, cefsharp

While sharing a screen in a webview, I want to select another screen than the default screen, I want to hook the getdisplayMedia event and use it.

I'm using it like this, but now only the main screen is shared.

```
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("use-fake-ui-for-media-stream","1");
```

How can I control a screen other than the default screen?

Comment: Try searching on https://magpcss.org/ceforum/index.php I believe there has been a similar question asked previously (from memory it's not currently supported).

Comment: This is not a solution. I would like to know how to handle other share windows.

Comment: I don't believe what you are trying is currently supported. I'm not saying there is s solution as I don't believe there is one currently. Search or ask on ceforum to confirm.

Comment: It's important to remember that CefSharp is just one of many chromium embedded framework(CEF) wrappers. CEF has it's own support forum at https://magpcss.org/ceforum/index.php to determine if CefSharp supports a feature you need to confirm that CEF supports that feature.

Comment: ok, thanks.  
I'll look for it